# Add querystring parameters in url using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on e-commerce website using angular.

On product listing page I am applying multiple filters.
what I wanted is,

when I am applying filters that filter type and value should reflect in the url as a querystring parameter.

Is there any way I can do in angularjs.

note:-I am not using **angular2**

Comment: take a look at [angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing), url-parameters section

Comment: I am using angular-route

Comment: I have come up with the 2 solutions.

1) $route.updateParams({'name','value'})
2) $location.search('name','value')